# MainPage.xaml file not loading properly in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to workout with silver light in Visual Studio 2010 Professional. I have installed SilverLight SDK 4 as Visual Studio says, as the SDK 5 requires SP1.
After this installation i successfully created a SilverLight Applicatioin. But when I load MainPage.xaml file, it was showing exception. I refresh it, re-create the project but nothing works.

```
System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.SilverlightMetadataContext.SilverlightXamlExtensionImplementations.<GetXmlNamespaceCompatibilityMappings>d__8.MoveNext()

at MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionProjectNode.BuildSubsumption()
```

at MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionProjectNode.SubsumingNamespace(Identifier identifier)

```
at MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.BuildScope(PrefixScope parentScope, IParseContext context)
```

I am new to SilverLight so i have no idea what is going on.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Can you post the minimum code that reproduces this problem.

Comment: Funny thing is i did not write a single line of code. This exception occurs when Design view is loaded.

Comment: Visual Studio asks me to install two things and i did. After creation of project this problem appear.

Comment: What two things where they?

Comment: 1. SilverLight 4 toolkit
2. SilverLight Developer Runtime